# What is the distribution of $Y = \varphi(X)$ where $\varphi(x) = F_X(x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let $X$ be a random variable (absolutely) continuous with
$F_X$ distribution; which is strictly increasing and with inverse $F_X^{-1}(u)$, for every $u \in [0,1]$. What is the distribution of $Y = \varphi(X)$ where $\varphi(x) =F_X(x)$?

My try:

$$y = \varphi(x)$$

$$P(Y\leq y)$$
$$=P(\varphi(x)\leq y)$$
$$=P(X\leq \varphi^{-1}(y)) = y$$

So then:

$\qquad$ $F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}y \qquad if \qquad0\leq y \leq 1, \\ 1 \qquad if \qquad 1 \leq y \end{cases}$

I´m not sure if this attept is correct.

Comment: You are right. I already corrected it, tanks.

Comment: Now I agree with your computation, except that $F_Y(y)$ isn't 0 when $y > 1$ but instead it's ...  what?  Then, you should be able to recognize $F_Y$ as the cdf of a well known distribution.

Comment: True, because it´s the distribution formula. So like that it would be correct?

Comment: I disagree with your correction.  As it stands you are claiming that $P(Y \le 2) = 2$.  And you still haven't said which well known distribution $Y$ has...

Comment: I don´t know the name for that distirbution. But I made a new correction. I´m not sure if y have to establish a value for the negative y´s.

Comment: Yes, your expression for $F_Y$ needs to give the correct answer for all real values of $y$.  As for the name, it's a very common one.  I think you should do a little research.  Sketching the cdf and/or the corresponding pdf may help you to recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $y\in [0,1]$

\begin{align}P(Y\leq y)
&=P(\varphi(\color{red}{X})\leq y)\\
&=P(X\leq \varphi^{-1}(y)) \\&= F_X(\varphi^{-1}(y))\\
&=\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(y)) \\&=y\end{align}

So then:

$\qquad$ $F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad if \qquad y\le 0\\y \qquad if \qquad0\leq y \leq 1, \\ 1 \qquad if \qquad 1 \leq y \end{cases}$

The density function is

$\qquad$ $f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad if \qquad y\le 0\\1 \qquad if \qquad0\leq y \leq 1, \\ 0 \qquad if \qquad 1 \leq y \end{cases}$

It is the uniform distribution.